# overflow-x not working css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple scrolling parent div. in which child div should be stacked horizontally.

[slackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-oftsbx?file=pages%2Fabout%2Fabout.css)

But it is not working. child divs are wrapped after div width end. Please help.

```css
#outerContainer {
      width: 100%;
      height: 150px;
      background: red;
      overflow: hidden;
      overflow-x: scroll;
    }
    
    .card {
      float: left;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100px;
      height: 150px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      background: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<div id="outerContainer">
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: After opening your stackblitz all I see in rendered space is 'Welcome to Ionic' website. Where problem is visible?

Comment: Click on the "About" @AndrzejZiółek

Comment: Plz click on about tab

Comment: @raju what so you exactly want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#outerContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `float:left;` from `.card` class and add `white-space:nowrap;` in `#outerContainer`

```css
#outerContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerContainer">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Outer container is 100% wide

Answer (score 0):

```css
#outerContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerContainer">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Your `card` elements go to second row. `flex` can make it a bit easier.

Comment: Adding a working demo that fixes the issue is always a good option there's an option to add code snippet above the text area where you've added your answer.